# python inspect identifying function that are overridden

Tags: python, overriding, inspect

I have something like

```
def inspection():
    inspect.stack()
    ...

class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        # do stuff
        inspection()

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        super(B, self).foo()
        # do other stuff
        inspection()

b = B()
b.foo()
```

I'm using the inspect module to analyze the stack from within both implementations of foo. I want to be able to tell the two functions apart based on the information from inspect.

I can get the function name (not helpful) and I can get the object but it just tells me it's an instance of B in both cases.

Comment: Both cases? You've only shown one case.

Comment: I've tried to clarify, the inspection() function is called in both implementations of foo(). I'm having trouble telling the two apart using the result of inspect.stack(). I guessing there is some value buried in the stack information that I dont know about that would be helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just needed do some more research. in [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html), I found Frame.f_code.co_firstlineno, which I can use to uniquely identify which implementation of foo() I'm in.